# Improve Adaboost that using weighted logistic regression instead of decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, weighted-regression, adaboost, bayes-optimal-classifier

I implemented Adaboost that using weighted logistic regression instead of decision trees and I managed to get to 0.5% error, I'm trying to improve it for days with no success and I know it possible to get with him to 0% error, hope you guys could help me do it.

My logistic regression algorithm:

Lg.py:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin_tnc
class LogistReg:
    def __init__(self,X,y,w):
        self.X = np.c_[np.ones((X.shape[0],1)),X]
        self.y = np.copy(y[:,np.newaxis])
        self.y[self.y==-1]=0
        self.theta = np.zeros((self.X.shape[1],1))
        self.weights = w
    
    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-x))
    
    def net_input(self, theta, x):
        return np.dot(x,theta)
    
    def probability(self,theta, x):
        return self.sigmoid(self.net_input(theta,x))
    
    def cost_function(self,theta,x,y):
        m = x.shape[0]
        tmp = (y*np.log(self.probability(theta,x)) + (1-y)*np.log(1-self.probability(theta,x)))
        total_cost = -(1.0/m )* np.sum(tmp*self.weights)/np.sum(self.weights)
        return total_cost

    def gradient(self,theta,x,y):
        m = x.shape[0]
        return (1.0/m)*np.dot(x.T,(self.sigmoid(self.net_input(theta,x))-y)*self.weights)

    def fit(self):
        opt_weights = fmin_tnc(func=self.cost_function,x0=self.theta,fprime=self.gradient,
        args=(self.X,self.y.flatten()))
        self.theta = opt_weights[0][:,np.newaxis]
        return self
    
    def predict(self,x):
        tmp_x = np.c_[np.ones((x.shape[0],1)),x]
        probs = self.probability(self.theta,tmp_x)
        probs[probs<0.5] = -1
        probs[probs>=0.5] = 1
        return probs.squeeze()
    
    def accuracy(self,x, actual_clases, probab_threshold = 0.5):
        predicted_classes  = (self.predict(x)>probab_threshold).astype(int)
        predicted_classes = predicted_classes.flatten()
        accuracy = np.mean(predicted_classes == actual_clases)
        return accuracy*100.0
```

My Adaboost using WLR:

adaboost_lg.py:

```py
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.datasets import make_gaussian_quantiles
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from plotting import plot_adaboost, plot_staged_adaboost
    from Lg import LogistReg
    class AdaBoostLg:
        """ AdaBoost enemble classifier from scratch """
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.stumps = None
            self.stump_weights = None
            self.errors = None
            self.sample_weights = None
    
        def _check_X_y(self, X, y):
            """ Validate assumptions about format of input data"""
            assert set(y) == {-1, 1}, 'Response variable must be ±1'
            return X, y
    
        def fit(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, iters: int):
            """ Fit the model using training data """
            X, y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
            n = X.shape[0]
    
            # init numpy arrays
            self.sample_weights = np.zeros(shape=(iters, n))
            self.stumps = np.zeros(shape=iters, dtype=object)
            self.stump_weights = np.zeros(shape=iters)
            self.errors = np.zeros(shape=iters)
    
            # initialize weights uniformly
            self.sample_weights[0] = np.ones(shape=n) / n
    
            for t in range(iters):
                # fit  weak learner
                curr_sample_weights = self.sample_weights[t]
                stump = LogistReg(X,y,curr_sample_weights)
                #stump = LogisticRegression()
                #stump = stump.fit(X, y, sample_weight=curr_sample_weights)
                stump  = stump.fit()
                # calculate error and stump weight from weak learner prediction
                stump_pred = stump.predict(X)
                err = curr_sample_weights[(stump_pred != y)].sum()# / n
                stump_weight = np.log((1 - err) / err) / 2
    
                # update sample weights
                new_sample_weights = (
                    curr_sample_weights * np.exp(-stump_weight * y * stump_pred)
                )
                
                new_sample_weights /= new_sample_weights.sum()
    
                # If not final iteration, update sample weights for t+1
                if t+1 < iters:
                    self.sample_weights[t+1] = new_sample_weights
    
                # save results of iteration
                self.stumps[t] = stump
                self.stump_weights[t] = stump_weight
                self.errors[t] = err
    
            return self
    
        def predict(self, X):
            """ Make predictions using already fitted model """
            stump_preds = np.array([stump.predict(X) for stump in self.stumps])
            return np.sign(np.dot(self.stump_weights, stump_preds))
    
    def make_toy_dataset(n: int = 100, random_seed: int = None):
        """ Generate a toy dataset for evaluating AdaBoost classifiers """
        
        n_per_class = int(n/2)
        
        if random_seed:
            np.random.seed(random_seed)
    
        X, y = make_gaussian_quantiles(n_samples=n, n_features=2, n_classes=2)
        
        return X, y*2-1
    
    
    # assign our individually defined functions as methods of our classifier
    
    if __name__ =='__main__':
        X, y = make_toy_dataset(n=10, random_seed=10)
        # y[y==-1] = 0
        plot_adaboost(X, y)
    
        clf = AdaBoostLg().fit(X, y, iters=20)
        #plot_adaboost(X, y, clf)
    
        train_err = (clf.predict(X) != y).mean()
        #print(f'Train error: {train_err:.1%}')
        plot_staged_adaboost(X, y, clf, 20)
        plt.show()
```

The 20th iteration result:
[image: 20th_iteration]

The 50th iteration result:
[image: 50th]

It seems to me like the machine isn't learning in every regression iteration. I get the same result, even after the 50th iteration. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, maybe my fit function not implemented well? or maybe my cost function?

Comment: What exactly do you need help?

Comment: It seems to me like the machine isn't learning in every regression iteration. I get the same result, even after the 50th iteration. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, maybe my fit function not implemented like needed? or maybe my cost function?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be pretty standard.  With logistic regression as the base estimator, the adaptive boosting stops adding value after very few iterations.  I put together [a little notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/CV483796.ipynb) to illustrate, using `sklearn`s [`AdaBoostClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html), which allows you to set your own `base_estimator`.)

Note that unlike in gradient boosting, you can theoretically get a nonlinear model at the end, because the sigmoid link function gets applied to each of the base models before averaging predictions, not after summing.  However, the examples in the notebook don't show any strongly nonlinear results.  I suspect this is just because logistic regression fits too well, so that the misclassified points are "balanced" in such a way that the later iterations don't have much effect.

Comment: you can make it work by applying a different link function to linear models, like c-log-log, or by changing. Fact is logit function is used by adaboost itself, so the weak learners stay linear when stacked.

Comment: if it was so neural nets would be linear models

Comment: what are you talking about? adaboost is a binary classification algorithm

Comment: Ah, sorry, I slipped into thinking about gradient boosting rather than adaptive boosting.

Comment: ...in fact, that same distinction invalidates the original answer: adaboost doesn't average the linear models results themselves, but the outcomes after the sigmoid link (and OPs code goes even further, only averaging the hard classification outcome).  The correct answer will be more nuanced.  I'll either delete or redraft this answer in a while.

Answer (score 1):

To build off of another comment, boosting with a linear base estimator does not add complexity as it would with trees.  So to increase accuracy in this setup you have to inject that complexity (extra dimensions where the data is linearly separable) typically by adding in interaction terms or polynomial expansion terms and let the boosting take care of the regularization of your coefficients.

Sklearn has a simple method for polynomial expansion with and without interaction terms:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html